# Getting Object's name in stdClass

Tags: stdclass

I have a string like this.

```
    {
  "type": "item",
  "version": "3.10.3",
  "basic": {
    "name": "",
    "rune": {
      "isrune": false,
      "tier": 1,
      "type": "red"
    },
    "gold": {
      "base": 0,
      "total": 0,
      "sell": 0,
      "purchasable": false
    },
    "group": "",
    "description": "",
    "colloq": ";",
    "plaintext": "",
    "consumeable": false,
    "stacks": 1,
    "depth": 1,
    "consumed": false,
    "consumeOnFull": false,
    "from": [],
    "into": [],
    "specialRecipe": 0,
    "inStore": true,
    "hideFromAll": false,
    "requiredChampion": "",
    "stats": {
      "FlatHPPoolMod": 0,
      "rFlatHPModPerLevel": 0,
      "FlatMPPoolMod": 0,
      "rFlatMPModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentHPPoolMod": 0,
      "PercentMPPoolMod": 0,
      "FlatHPRegenMod": 0,
      "rFlatHPRegenModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentHPRegenMod": 0,
      "FlatMPRegenMod": 0,
      "rFlatMPRegenModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentMPRegenMod": 0,
      "FlatArmorMod": 0,
      "rFlatArmorModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentArmorMod": 0,
      "rFlatArmorPenetrationMod": 0,
      "rFlatArmorPenetrationModPerLevel": 0,
      "rPercentArmorPenetrationMod": 0,
      "rPercentArmorPenetrationModPerLevel": 0,
      "FlatPhysicalDamageMod": 0,
      "rFlatPhysicalDamageModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentPhysicalDamageMod": 0,
      "FlatMagicDamageMod": 0,
      "rFlatMagicDamageModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentMagicDamageMod": 0,
      "FlatMovementSpeedMod": 0,
      "rFlatMovementSpeedModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentMovementSpeedMod": 0,
      "rPercentMovementSpeedModPerLevel": 0,
      "FlatAttackSpeedMod": 0,
      "PercentAttackSpeedMod": 0,
      "rPercentAttackSpeedModPerLevel": 0,
      "rFlatDodgeMod": 0,
      "rFlatDodgeModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentDodgeMod": 0,
      "FlatCritChanceMod": 0,
      "rFlatCritChanceModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentCritChanceMod": 0,
      "FlatCritDamageMod": 0,
      "rFlatCritDamageModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentCritDamageMod": 0,
      "FlatBlockMod": 0,
      "PercentBlockMod": 0,
      "FlatSpellBlockMod": 0,
      "rFlatSpellBlockModPerLevel": 0,
      "PercentSpellBlockMod": 0,
      "FlatEXPBonus": 0,
      "PercentEXPBonus": 0,
      "rPercentCooldownMod": 0,
      "rPercentCooldownModPerLevel": 0,
      "rFlatTimeDeadMod": 0,
      "rFlatTimeDeadModPerLevel": 0,
      "rPercentTimeDeadMod": 0,
      "rPercentTimeDeadModPerLevel": 0,
      "rFlatGoldPer10Mod": 0,
      "rFlatMagicPenetrationMod": 0,
      "rFlatMagicPenetrationModPerLevel": 0,
      "rPercentMagicPenetrationMod": 0,
      "rPercentMagicPenetrationModPerLevel": 0
    },
    "tags": [],
    "maps": {
      "1": true,
      "8": true,
      "10": true,
      "12": true
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "1001": {
      "name": "Boots of Speed",
      "group": "BootsNormal",
      "description": "<groupLimit>Limited to 1.</groupLimit><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Enhanced Movement:</unique> +25 Movement Speed<br><br><i>(Unique Passives with the same name don't stack.)</i>",
      "colloq": ";",
      "plaintext": "Slightly increases Movement Speed",
      "into": [
        "3006",
        "3047",
        "3020",
        "3158",
        "3111",
        "3117",
        "3009"
      ],
      "image": {
        "full": "1001.png",
        "sprite": "item0.png",
        "group": "item",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "w": 48,
        "h": 48
      },
      "gold": {
        "base": 325,
        "purchasable": true,
        "total": 325,
        "sell": 227
      },
      "tags": [
        "MOVEMENT",
        "BOOTS"
      ],
      "stats": {
        "FlatMovementSpeedMod": 25
      }
    },
    "1004": {
      "name": "Faerie Charm",
      "description": "<stats>+3 Mana Regen per 5 seconds</stats>",
      "colloq": ";",
      "plaintext": "Slightly increases Mana Regen",
      "into": [
        "3037",
        "3096",
        "3028",
        "3070",
        "3073",
        "1080",
        "3165"
      ],
      "image": {
        "full": "1004.png",
        "sprite": "item0.png",
        "group": "item",
        "x": 48,
        "y": 0,
        "w": 48,
        "h": 48
      },
      "gold": {
        "base": 180,
        "purchasable": true,
        "total": 180,
        "sell": 126
      },
      "tags": [
        "MANAREGEN"
      ],
      "stats": {
        "FlatMPRegenMod": 0.6
      }
    },
    "1006": {
```

its going like this I'm trying to get 1006 from "1006: { but i cant

```
$iveri =      $iresponse->body;
    foreach($iveri->data as $esya)
            {
            print($esya);

            }
```

Because it's object, but i want it's name but i cant find a way to get that can you help me, I'm building database from that like getting values insade it and they will their id's they are id's of items so they cant be auto assing they had to be like in array.

Comment: what language are you using? that looks like valid JSON, which your language should take care of eg in PHP just use json_decode($string).

Comment: I could use it but, as i said i need to push them all in to database so, i need foreach anyways i still cant get that, It's not problem otherwise i can use stdclass and getting value but i cant get this value...

Answer (score 0):

`1006` in your example is a key value, you need to slightly modify your loop syntax:

```
foreach($ivery->data as $key=>$esya) {
  print $key; // This will be '1006'
  print $esya;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I want